# Get most common value for each value in row - pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This may be a duplicate please let me know.

I have a pandas df like this:

| id | name | Common |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | A |  |
| One | A |  |
| One | A |  |
| One | B |  |
| Two | C |  |

I'd like to output something like this:

Where the most common name for each id is placed in the common column.

| id | name | Common |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | A |
| One | A | A |
| One | A | A |
| One | B | A |
| Two | C | C |

I've tried this but at this point i'm throwing darts in the dark

```
df.groupby(['id', 'name']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['id'])['name'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])` or use `x.mode()[0]` inside.

Comment: @QuangHoang This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```py
df['Common'] = df.groupby('id')['name'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    id name Common
0  One    A      A
1  One    A      A
2  One    A      A
3  One    B      A
4  Two    C      C
```

Answer (score 0):

A longer (potentially slower) process is to pivot and map:

```py
df.assign(Common = df.id.map(df.pivot(None, 'id', 'name').mode().T.squeeze()))
 
    id name Common
0  One    A      A
1  One    A      A
2  One    A      A
3  One    B      A
4  Two    C      C
```